# Error insertar variable en consulta Python 3

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7

Aquí tengo mi consulta

```
# Consulta
def run_query(self, query, parameters = ()):
    with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
        conn.commit()
    #return result
    return [rec for rec in result]
```

Aquí tengo el campo ULTASIGNACION y tengo la variable miasignacion1 que tomo de un Entry

```
    query = 'SELECT * FROM escuela WHERE ULTASIGNACION = %s', (miasignacion1.get(), )
    db_rows = self.run_query(self.query)
    #Rellenando los Datos
    for row in db_rows:
        self.tree.insert('', 0, text = row[0], value=row[1:13])
```

Me aparece este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que yo quiero hacer en tomar la variable que entra por el Entry y filtrar la consulta, si alguien me puede señalar el error u otra manera de hacerlo, se lo agradecería.
De antemano gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: puede que `miasignacion1.get()` esté retornando un número entero, en ese caso deberias usar `%d` dentro de la consulta en vez de `%s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, tu variable con la query no es un atributo de instancia, a no ser que al copiar te faltara el `self.`, debe ser:

```
query = 'SELECT * FROM escuela WHERE ULTASIGNACION = %s', (miasignacion1.get(), )
db_rows = self.run_query(query)
```

o:

```
self.query = 'SELECT * FROM escuela WHERE ULTASIGNACION = %s', (miasignacion1.get()
db_rows = self.run_query(self.query)
```

En cuanto al error, el problema es que **`query` es una tupla** y el método `run_query` espera dos argumentos, el primero con la query y el segundo una tupla con los parámetros, argumentos que pasa directamente a `cursor.execute`.

Cuando haces:

```
self.run_query(query)
```

la llamas así:

```
self.run_query(query=('SELECT * FROM escuela WHERE ULTASIGNACION = %s', miasignacion1.get()), parameters=()
```

es decir, recibe una tupla como query. Debes hacer:

```
query = 'SELECT * FROM escuela WHERE ULTASIGNACION = %s', (miasignacion1.get(), )
self.run_query(*query)
```

o:

```
query = 'SELECT * FROM escuela WHERE ULTASIGNACION = ?'
db_rows = self.run_query(query, (miasignacion1.get(), ))
```

Por cierto, no uses nunca formato de cadenas en cualquiera de sus formas o concatenado si la query es parametrizable, expones innecesariamente la base de datos a ataques de inyección de código, en vez de:

```
'SELECT * FROM escuela WHERE ULTASIGNACION = %s'
```

debes hacer, por ejemplo:

```
'SELECT * FROM escuela WHERE ULTASIGNACION = ?'
```

Comment: Muchas gracias FJSevilla, pude resolver el problema, ademas gracias por la aclaración del uso de formato cadenas en query parametrizable, le hice los cambio como sugiere, funciona perfecto, MUCHAS GRACIAS.

Comment: Hola, FJSevilla, me funciono muy bien la instrucción, entiendo que debo mandar una tupla en la consulta, ahora cuando agrego un segundo campo como lo describo acá generar un error, no entiendo si estoy mandando la tupla en el variable parameters, que mando a continuación, si me puede dar una referencia mi error. Agradecido de antemano.
self.query = 'SELECT * FROM escuela WHERE SEXO1 = ?, BAUTIZADO1 = ?'
parameters = (misexo1.get(), mibautizado1.get())
db_rows = self.run_query(self.query, parameters)

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Proyecto4\index5.py", line 830, in listar_record
    db_rows = self.run_query(self.query, parameters)
  File "C:\Proyecto4\index5.py", line 254, in run_query
    result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error

Comment: En cuanto a tu problema, la query debería ser `'SELECT * FROM escuela WHERE SEXO1 = ? AND BAUTIZADO1 = ?'`, te falta el operador `AND`.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la paciencia, y por tu ayuda FJSevilla, si he aprendido que cada respuesta que me ayuda debo aceptarla, solo que cuando la hago dice que tengo poca reputación para subir el puntaje, es lo que entiendo, sin embargo voy a entrar al link que me recomiendas para seguir las instrucciones.

Comment: Muchas gracias,  – FJSevilla, efectivamente se resolvió el problema al colocar el operar AND, muchas gracias, llevo lo que va de la pandemia aprendiendo Python y tu ayuda ha sido muy valiosa. Intente votar y ya me dejo, de manera que ya hice mi primer voto positivo. Saludos

Comment: De nada, por cierto WHERE puede combinarse con muchos más operadores, incluidos OR y AND, por si te interesa o necesitas en un futuro para queries más complejas: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-where/ ¡Saludos y feliz aprendizaje!, yo ando en algo parecido, profundizando en Rust... :)

Comment: ok muchas gracias voy a revisarlo